# BASH Command save to variable with a variable in the command

Tags: bash, variables, command

I have a command I want to run first I ran another command to get a directory which is saved in a variable:

```
path_white="/sys/block/sdb"
```

Then I want to run another command using this variable and store the output in a variable.  I get errors and don't know what I am doing wrong.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
path_pci_white=$(ll $path_white | xargs | cut -d / -f 8 | cut -b 6-13)
```

it seems that it is not running the entire command below is the error

```
/sys/block/sdb : is a directory
```

when i run

```
ll /sys/block/sdb | xargs | cut -d / -f 8 | cut -b 6-13
```

in the terminal i get what i want output I just want to use a variable and put the output into a variable

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `path_pci_white=$(ll $(path_white) | xargs | cut -d / -f 8 | cut -b 6-13)`   path_withe between parenthesis ?

Comment: when i do that i get a different error  such that:  path_white: command not found, and ll: command not found

Comment: That's because Luc wrote $(path_white) when he meant ${path_white} (at least I hope he meant that).  $(path_white) tries to run a program called path_white, as you have seen, which does not work.

Comment: @bing281: have you noticed how you have a trailing slash on the path in one case and not the other?  Try changing that around and see if it matters.

Comment: yes that was just an example edit fixed.

Comment: John also ${path_white} gives me the error ll: command not found

Comment: answer accepted below change ll to ls -l however John Z.  and Luc M also helped with the ${}

Comment: @JohnZwinck Opps, yes I meant  ${path_white}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ll` is an alias for `ls -l`, and aliases aren't defined in shell scripts. Use an explicit `ls -l` instead.

Comment: The OP didn't even state that he was running these things in a script--good psychic debugging!

Comment: Or source your rc file in your script, though I don't think this would be considered best practice.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a pipe after xargs.  xargs takes as arguments the command it will run.  Otherwise there is no point to it.

Comment: I don't actually follow you, however the last command above works perfectly in the terminal.  ll /sys/block/sdb | xargs | cut -d / -f 8 | cut -b 6-13

Comment: Oh, then the xargs part is useless and should be removed, as all it is doing is echoing on stdout what it gets on stdin.  Can you show us the output of that `ll` command on your system, and the desired output of the pipeline?